# Add missing dates to an array

Tags: php

I have the following array:

```
Array ( [2010-10-30] => 1 [2010-11-11] => 1 [2010-11-13] => 11 )
```

I am trying to fill in the array with all the missing dates between the first and last elements. I was attempting using the following but got nowhere:

```
foreach($users_by_date as $key => $value){
    $real_next_day = date($key, time()+86400);
    $array_next_day = key(next($users_by_date));
    if($real_next_day != $array_next_day){
      $users_by_date[$real_next_day] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible for the first and last element to not be the lowest/highest of the date range? Or will this be guaranteed?

Comment: It will be guaranteed, there is a function (ksort()) before this that will sort it anyway, just in case!

Comment: Alright. Give me a sec, but just while I'm doing this and as a general rule, don't use a foreach when you're modifying the keys/indexes of an array. The foreach is just to enumerate the elements and "locks" element changes while iterating through (not so much lock as it's a copy, but you can think of it in these terms). For more information see PHP's foreach manual: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Is it practical to index by timestamp instead of formatted date string? A solution might be a bit cleaner if you can.

Answer (score 8):

The DateTime, DateInterval and DatePeriod classes can really help out here.

```
$begin=date_create('2010-10-30');
$end=date_create('2010-11-13');
$i = new DateInterval('P1D');
$period=new DatePeriod($begin,$i,$end);

foreach ($period as $d){
  $day=$d->format('Y-m-d');
  $usercount= isset($users_by_date[$day]) ? $users_by_date[$day] :0;
  echo "$day $usercount"; 
}
```

Comment: Not sure what, but something is wrong with this (besides the incomplete new DatePeriod.

$begin = date_create('2010-10-30');
  $end = date_create('2010-11-13');
  $i = new DateInterval('P1D');
  $period = new DatePeriod($begin, $i, $end);
  foreach($period as $d){
   $day = $d->format('Y-m-d');
   $usercount = isset($users_by_date[$day]) ? $users_by_date[$day] :0;
   echo "$day $usercount";
  }
  print_r($users_by_date);

Comment: @SHutch: SO ate my original reply. Looks like I missed a bit of text when recreating it.  Fixed now.

Comment: Unfortunately host is running PHP v5.2.14 so this won't work :(

Comment: @SHutch: that is very sad. I suggest pie (or cake).  If your sysadmin isn't susceptible to bribery, then you can eat it yourself. Either way, you feel better.

Answer (score 5):

I have been waiting for a chance to try out [DateTime](http://www.php.net/datetime) and [DateInterval](http://www.php.net/dateinterval) objects in PHP 5.3, your question was the perfect opportunity to do just that. Note that this code will not work with PHP versions earlier than 5.3

```
<?php
$dates = array('2010-10-30' => 1, '2010-11-01' => 1, '2010-11-13' => 1);

// get start and end out of array
reset($dates);
$start = new DateTime(key($dates));

end($dates);
$end   = new DateTime(key($dates));

foreach (new DatePeriod($start, new DateInterval('P1D'), $end) as $date) {
    $dateKey = $date->format('Y-m-d'); // get properly formatted date out of DateTime object
    if (!isset($dates[$dateKey])) {
        $dates[$dateKey] = 1;
    }
}

print_r($dates);
```

Comment: Unfortunately host is running PHP v5.2.14 :(

Comment: +1 for the 'foreach' loop over the date range and adding the values to the same array. I still have to sort the array after to keep the order of the dates as they are added to the end. I had a solution where I copied them over, but liked yours more.

Answer (score 1):

The functions you are looking for (but not using in your example) are [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) & [diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

You would get the day range between your two dates `$numdiff`, and simply do something in a loop that would do:

```
for ($i=1; $i<=$numdiff; $i++) { 
   echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("2010-10-30 +".$i." day"));
}
```

Result should be something like:

```
2010-10-31
2010-11-01
2010-11-02...
```

You could then pop that into your array as needed. Hope that gets you started in the right direction.

Comment: strtotime is sort of expensive, but as long as we're not worried about that, this solution seems great (for PHP < 5.3).

Answer (score 0):

For indexes using timestamps, you can generate your array easily using the range function.

```
$startStamp = ...
$endStamp = ...
$oneDay = 60*60*24;

$timeIndexes = range($startStamp, $endStamp, $oneDay);
$filler = array_fill(0, count($timeIndexes), null);
$timeArray = array_combine($timeIndexes, $filler);
```

I am not sure what values you want in the array, but hopefully it is relatively straight-forward from here.

If you are going to be converting every timestamp to a formatted date string anyhow and would just prefer to use date strings in the first place, consider this modification.

```
$dateStringIndexes = array_map(
    function ($t) {
        return date('Y-m-d', $t);
    },
    $timeIndexes
);
```

Of course, since you are on PHP 5.2, you will likely have to compromise with a foreach loop instead of the closure.

Answer (score 0):

This is the PHP 5.2 capable function I came up with that works.

Thanks guys

```
reset($users_by_date);
    $date = key($users_by_date);

    end($users_by_date);
    $end =  key($users_by_date);

    while(strtotime($date) <= strtotime($end)){
        $datearray[] = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));
        $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($date)));
    }

    foreach($datearray as $key => $value){
        if(!isset($users_by_date[$value])){
            $users_by_date[$value] = 0;
        }
    }
    ksort($users_by_date);
```